# Empty soapAction in generated WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jax-ws

I'm trying to generate a WSDL from my Java code using JAX-WS.

Everything seems to work OK, except that for my operations in the WSDL the soapAction remains empty.

Here is my code:

```
@WebService
public class MyClass {
    public MyStuff queryStuff(String myParam) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

The generated WSDL contains this:

```
<wsdl:operation name="queryStuff">
    <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>
    <wsdl:input name="queryStuffRequest">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:input>
    <wsdl:output name="queryStuffResponse">
        <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>
    </wsdl:output>
</wsdl:operation>
```

I can't tell what I'm doing wrong. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to annotate your method with `@WebMehtod`.

**Example**

```
@WebService(name = "dataService", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/vap/webservice/dataservice/definition")
@SOAPBinding(style = Style.DOCUMENT, use = Use.LITERAL, parameterStyle = ParameterStyle.WRAPPED)
public interface DataSEI {

    @WebMethod(action = "createAction", operationName = "create")
    DataTransferObjectStatusContainer create(
            @WebParam(name = "objects", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/vap/webservice/dataservice/definition")
            DataTranferObjectContainer pObjectsContainer,
            @WebParam(name = "atomic", targetNamespace = "http://example.com/vap/webservice/dataservice/definition")
            boolean pAsAtomicOperation) throws Fault;
}
```

**NOTE:** A lot of the annotations from the example are not required, but I put it there to show you all the things you can do with JAX-WS

Comment: If you do not add the `@WebMethod` annotation, for sure JAX-WS will not generate any action. Can you update your question with your annotated method and the complete generated WSDL?

Another thing that you might add to your question to help us to help you is your jax-ws endpoint configuration, an explanation about how are you generating/publishing the web service and also how are you obtaining the WSDL.

Comment: I realized my mistake. I was using an Eclipse-Plugin that (I'm guessing here) didn't recognize the @WebMethod-Annotation. Using the wsgen tool it all worked fine just as you suggested. Thank you for your help! :)